# .htaccess - redirect from subdirectory to root directory and remember in enviroment requested path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have some difficulties with the mod_rewrite rules for language folders. I want to rewrite any request on:
www.example.com/lang/*
to:
www.example.com/*

I add rule

```
RewriteRule ^lang/(.*)$ \/$1
```

As I use several language I'd like to save in enviroment wich exactly language in URL is typed at first opening of site.

Futher I use rule

```
SetEnvIf Referer "www.example.com/lang1/" LANG=1
SetEnvIf Referer "www.example.com/lang2/" LANG=2
```

So I got language to show on site

However I could not get this enviroment when typing address www.example.com/lang1/ in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is an internal rewrite (the new path is used instead of the old one), there is no communication with the client and therefore no new Referer set.

But using the referer is always unreliable. Consider modifying the RewriteRule so that it contains the original request URI in the query string.

This would be

```
RewriteRule ^lang/(.*)$ \/$1&uri=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

if your requests contain a query string, and

```
RewriteRule ^lang/(.*)$ \/$1?uri=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

if not. The original URI would then be contained in the variable `$_GET['uri']`.

Comment: The original URI would then be contained NOT in the variable $_SERVER['uri'] but in $_GET['uri'] And it works. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, typing error. Fixed. Thanks for notification.

Comment: If it works, please consider accepting and maybe upvoting the answer.

Comment: And if request could contains or not query string is there a way to change or not ? to & in rule: $1__?/&__uri=

Comment: In my case I made such redirect for two conditions with query and not: RewriteRule ^lang/(.*)$ /$1?uri=%{REQUEST_URI}$2 [P,QSA]